# Missing hyphens and spaces on pasting content in iframe from pdf

Tags: asp.net, iframe, paste

I have created an editable iframe in asp.net. When i try to copy and paste content from pdf or from websites like wikipedia. Spaces and hyphens get disappeared in iframe.

Editable iframe creation code:

```
  <iframe id="editable">Some text here
  </iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
       var iframe = document.getElementById('editable');
       var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
       doc.body.innerHTML = iframe.textContent || iframe.innerHTML;
    // Make IFRAME editable
    if (doc.body.contentEditable) {
       doc.body.contentEditable = true;
    }
  }           
 </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Find the pdf file and program with iframe to paste the content from it from the following link, [hightail.com/download/ZUcxTXRZeDN0d0Z3SGNUQw](http://hightail.com/download/ZUcxTXRZeDN0d0Z3SGNUQw)

Comment: Use some javascript editor

Comment: @Aristos ok but i need to use iframe in my application for editing. Why is pasting have issues in iframe?

Comment: iframes are not made to be editors, thats why. Javascript editors also use iframe, but handle a lot of different situations. You can also add the javascript editor inside an iframe.

Comment: I am using an editor which uses iframe. And i face this issue when i try to paste some text from pdfs and wikipedia. Some hyphens at the end of line gets eaten by the editor.

Comment: Maybe they have not copied at the beginning from the pdf...

Comment: @Aristos Is there any alternative solution than javascript editor?

Comment: Upload the document file, and use a viewer for it

Comment: @Aristos- i have attached the pdf file and program with iframe to paste the content from it. https://www.hightail.com/download/ZUcxTXRZeDN0d0Z3SGNUQw